# Issue compiling nginx with pcre on ubuntu

Tags: nginx, pcre

I'm having problems building ngnix with the PCRE library on Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS. Configuring runs OK but the make command fails.  I'm fairly new to nginx and Linux in general so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Installation steps:

```
./configure --add-module=/home/ubuntu/mod_zip/mod_zip-master --with-http_image_filter_module --without-http_rewrite_module --with-pcre=../pcre-8.32
make
make install
```

Error

```
cd ../pcre-8.32 \
        && make libpcre.la
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ubuntu/pcre-8.32'
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_byte_order.lo
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_compile.lo
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_config.lo
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_dfa_exec.lo
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_exec.lo
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_fullinfo.lo
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_get.lo
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_globals.lo
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_jit_compile.lo
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_maketables.lo
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_newline.lo
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_ord2utf8.lo
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_refcount.lo
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_string_utils.lo
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_study.lo
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_tables.lo
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_ucd.lo
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_valid_utf8.lo
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_version.lo
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_xclass.lo
rm -f pcre_chartables.c
ln -s ./pcre_chartables.c.dist pcre_chartables.c
  CC     libpcre_la-pcre_chartables.lo
  CCLD   libpcre.la
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/pcre-8.32'
gcc -o objs/nginx \
        objs/src/core/nginx.o \
        objs/src/core/ngx_log.o \
        objs/src/core/ngx_palloc.o \
        objs/src/core/ngx_array.o \
        ...
        ...
        ...
        objs/addon/mod_zip-master/ngx_http_zip_module.o \
        objs/addon/mod_zip-master/ngx_http_zip_parsers.o \
        objs/addon/mod_zip-master/ngx_http_zip_file.o \
        objs/addon/mod_zip-master/ngx_http_zip_headers.o \
        objs/ngx_modules.o \
        -lpthread -lcrypt ../pcre-8.32/.libs/libpcre.a -lcrypto -lcrypto -lz -lgd
objs/src/core/nginx.o: In function `main':
/home/ubuntu/nginx-1.2.6/src/core/nginx.c:275: undefined reference to `ngx_regex_init'
objs/src/http/ngx_http_core_module.o: In function `ngx_http_gzip_disable':
/home/ubuntu/nginx-1.2.6/src/http/ngx_http_core_module.c:4918: undefined reference to `ngx_regex_compile'
objs/src/http/ngx_http_core_module.o: In function `ngx_http_gzip_ok':
/home/ubuntu/nginx-1.2.6/src/http/ngx_http_core_module.c:2218: undefined reference to `ngx_regex_exec_array'
objs/src/http/ngx_http_variables.o: In function `ngx_http_regex_compile':
/home/ubuntu/nginx-1.2.6/src/http/ngx_http_variables.c:2074: undefined reference to `ngx_regex_compile'
objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_ssi_filter_module.o: In function `ngx_http_ssi_regex_match':
/home/ubuntu/nginx-1.2.6/src/http/modules/ngx_http_ssi_filter_module.c:1882: undefined reference to `ngx_regex_compile'
objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_referer_module.o: In function `ngx_http_referer_variable':
/home/ubuntu/nginx-1.2.6/src/http/modules/ngx_http_referer_module.c:197: undefined reference to `ngx_regex_exec_array'
objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_referer_module.o: In function `ngx_http_add_regex_referer':
/home/ubuntu/nginx-1.2.6/src/http/modules/ngx_http_referer_module.c:582: undefined reference to `ngx_regex_compile'
objs/src/http/modules/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.o: In function `ngx_http_fastcgi_split_path_info':
/home/ubuntu/nginx-1.2.6/src/http/modules/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.c:2891: undefined reference to `ngx_regex_compile'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [objs/nginx] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ubuntu/nginx-1.2.6'
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

Thanks!

Comment: I've tried, but failed, to reproduce this problem, because I can't understand the error based on your posted output. Could you please post the whole output and your commands somewhere like pastebin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specify to not use the rewrite module, which means Nginx shouldn't need pcre. But then you specify the pcre location.

I think you should just remove the --with-pcre= parameter, then it should be fine. You don't need pcre anyway if you don't use the rewrite module.

Comment: The reason that I'm trying to include pcre is that it's required for using regular expressions in the location.

Comment: try to not disable mod rewrite then. i think then it should work